# Alter index all on table rebuild doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code in my SQL Server query:

```
USE TRANSPORTE;
GO

DECLARE
    @database_id INT = DB_ID(),
    @object_id   INT = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Reparaciones');

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (@database_id ,@object_id , NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

This is the result from that query:

[image]

When I want to run this code, it should rebuild the index but it doesn't work, the `avg_fragmentation_in_percent` should be 0:

```
alter index all on dbo.Reparaciones rebuild
```

Comment: Your table is not large enough for fragmentation to mean anything. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5365/154351

Comment: Also I don't know if it's possible to achieve (and maintain) 0 percent fragmentation _for a heap_.

Comment: I agree, the first thing you should worry about is why it's a heap and not a clustered index. Forget about fragmentation unless you know it's an issue